# Writing to separate columns instead of comma seperated for csv files in scrapy

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am working with scrapy and writing the data fetched from web pages in to CSV files

My `pipeline` code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.file_name = csv.writer(open('example.csv', 'wb'))
    self.file_name.writerow(['Title', 'Release Date','Director'])

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.file_name.writerow([item['Title'].encode('utf-8'),
                                item['Release Date'].encode('utf-8'),
                                item['Director'].encode('utf-8'),
                                ])
    return item
```

And my output format in CSV file is:

```
Title,Release Date,Director
And Now For Something Completely Different,1971,Ian MacNaughton
Monty Python And The Holy Grail,1975,Terry Gilliam and Terry Jones
Monty Python's Life Of Brian,1979,Terry Jones
.....
```

But is it possible to write `title` and its values into one column , `Release date` and its values into the next column,`Director` and its values into the next column (because CSV is comma separated values) in a CSV file like the format below.

```
        Title,                                 Release Date,            Director
And Now For Something Completely Different,      1971,              Ian MacNaughton
Monty Python And The Holy Grail,                 1975,     Terry Gilliam and Terry Jones
Monty Python's Life Of Brian,                    1979,              Terry Jones
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to signal that you are asking this question twice and [provide a link to the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10816241/1290420)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update** -- Code re-factored in order to:
>
> 1. use a generator function as suggested by @madjar and
> 2. fit more closely to the code snippet provided by the OP.

### The Target Output

I am trying an alternative using [`texttable`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable). It produces an identical output to that in the question. This output may be written to a csv file (the records will need massaging for the appropriate csv dialect, and I cannot find a way to still use the `csv.writer` and still get the padded spaces in each field.

```
                  Title,                      Release Date,             Director            
And Now For Something Completely Different,       1971,              Ian MacNaughton        
Monty Python And The Holy Grail,                  1975,       Terry Gilliam and Terry Jones 
Monty Python's Life Of Brian,                     1979,                Terry Jones
```

### The Code

Here is a sketch of the code you would need to produce the result above:

```py
from texttable import Texttable

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# Imagine data to be generated by Scrapy, for each record:
# a dictionary of three items. The first set ot functions
# generate the data for use in the texttable function

def process_item(item):
    # This massages each record in preparation for writing to csv
    item['Title'] = item['Title'].encode('utf-8') + ','
    item['Release Date'] = item['Release Date'].encode('utf-8') + ','
    item['Director'] = item['Director'].encode('utf-8')
    return item

def initialise_dataset():
    data = [{'Title' : 'Title',
         'Release Date' : 'Release Date',
         'Director' : 'Director'
         }, # first item holds the table header
            {'Title' : 'And Now For Something Completely Different',
         'Release Date' : '1971',
         'Director' : 'Ian MacNaughton'
         },
        {'Title' : 'Monty Python And The Holy Grail',
         'Release Date' : '1975',
         'Director' : 'Terry Gilliam and Terry Jones'
         },
        {'Title' : "Monty Python's Life Of Brian",
         'Release Date' : '1979',
         'Director' : 'Terry Jones'
         }
        ]

    data = [ process_item(item) for item in data ]
    return data

def records(data):
    for item in data:
        yield [item['Title'], item['Release Date'], item['Director'] ]

# this ends the data simulation part
# --------------------------------------------------------

def create_table(data):
    # Create the table
    table = Texttable(max_width=0)
    table.set_deco(Texttable.HEADER)
    table.set_cols_align(["l", "c", "c"])
    table.add_rows( records(data) )

    # split, remove the underlining below the header
    # and pull together again. Many ways of cleaning this...
    tt = table.draw().split('\n')
    del tt[1] # remove the line under the header
    tt = '\n'.join(tt)
    return tt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = initialise_dataset()
    table = create_table(data)
    print table
```

Comment: You could change the first two records to be generator expressions instead of lists in order to save twice the size of the input in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the credits. Here is my vote, your answer is the most useful here.

Answer (score 1):

TSV (tab separated values) might get you what you want, but it often turns ugly when the lines have very different length.

You can easily write a bit of code to produce such a table. The trick is that you need to have all the rows before outputting in order to compute the width of the columns.

You can find lots of snippets for that on the internet, [here is one I used before](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/09/04/pretty-printing-a-table-in-python/).

Comment: I dont think its a table, there is a chance to increase items, here we are increasing the columns, i mean if there are more items then columns will be increased.

Comment: All about is writing data in to individual columns rather than comma separated values.

Comment: You just have this tabular data that you want to output in a pretty human-readable format, right ? There is no way to put things directly into columns, you can just output string. So you have to compute yourself the width of the columns, and format accordingly.